# If NodeJS is single threaded, why we need to handle concurrency in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions

I am using nodejs and mongodb on the server side.

I could use `update if found` to handle a mongodb document for transaction handling e.g. -

```
// Pseudocode
var filter = { _id : 123, status : single };
db.myself.update(filter, new_document);
```

This will update myself status from single to committed. Other threads will not update as status is no longer single.

NodeJS runs in single thread. So, will the following code will also be transaction safe -

```
// Pseudocode
var filter = { _id = 123 };
db.myself.findOne(filter).toArray(function(err, result)) {
   if(!err) { 
      if(result.status == single) { // checking status manually
          db.myself.update(filter, new_document);
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: Not even slightly. Not only is there no benefit here but there is also a potential "race" where the content of the document as "found" may differ by the time you go you "alter" it. What you appear to be asking in an abstract way is something more like an implementation of [two phase commits](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/) which is described in the linked section there. Also don't confuse single thread with the inability to perform other requests. Node uses events to do exactly that.

Comment: Ok, nodeJS has event loop. Isn't event loop sequential? Can you please explain more?

Comment: Plenty of sources about how node works, but can two requests be issued at once? Yes. And that is largely the purpose of node and async programming. Your question needs to get to the point though about what you are trying to achieve, and I would suggest reading the two phase commits mentioned earlier and consider the question you really want to ask is "how to achive goal x" as your current presumptions are incorrect.

Comment: I understand that the second approach is wrong but was not able to visualize better as my understanding of nodejs eventloop and event handlers is not great. I will look into two phase commits. Thanks

Comment: Well you also might consider that this question in this form really has no other answer than "No" and "blah, blah, node is evented" and more of the same I have already stated. And it also smacks of not being very well researched or clear to your purpose other then "is this good/does this work". Just a bit of a heads up that you might not want to leave this laying around for scrutiny.